What to do if Linux kernel crashes without any dump output in console?
I have an aarch64 machine (based on rk3568) with kernel 4.19 and Ubuntu20.04. This machine sometimes stuck and crashes, without any output information, even in the debug serial tty console (ttyFIQ0).
This kernel is modified by myself and may contain bugs, I wonder:

how to tell if the crash is caused by hardware or software?
if it's software's problem, how can I debug the kernel?

I have tested echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger, and the kernel dumps well in ttyFIQ0. But the strange crashes dumps nothing.
I have enabled nmi_watchdog as follows:
# in CMDLINE
nmi_watchdog=1
nmi_watchdog=panic

# in /etc/sysctl.conf
kernel.panic = 10

it works well (reset the system in 10 seconds) with echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger, but not working when that crash happens.
